# Tooltips disappear after zoom in/out when using matplotlib mpld3

Tags: matplotlib, tooltip, mpld3

I have a matplotlib figure with tooltips on the point markers:
[image]

And the zoom in/out is working:

However after the zoom in/out is performed the tooltips no longer function: and even restoring the original (non-zoomed) size they do not come back.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide example code to reproduce this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you have any evidence this DOES work? Specifically: any example code showing tooltips and resizing?  If so i'd be glad to work with that - including showing my negative example.

Comment: It works for me in the scatter plot with tooltips example here: http://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html

Comment: Thanks v much. I had actually been working on the example anyways but had other items interfere. Will get it to you soon here.

Comment: That plot on your link displays the precise behavior (/problem) described in the OP. I have tested on Safari and Chrome on Yosemite.  You may not have followed the same steps shown from the OP .

Comment: The tooltips work for me after zooming and still work for me after restoring to original zoom. I am using Win 8, Chrome Version 44.0.2403.125 m

Comment: Interesting. I just got a windoze machine - let's see if we can get on the same page here.

Comment: Nope - i see same (wrong) behavior on Windoze.  Clearly we are doing different things. I have to refresh the page to get the tooltips back. btw "pan" *does* work.

Comment: Here is a though, are you using the pan-and-zoom tool (crossed arrows icon) or the box zoom (magnifier icon)?  While box zoom is active, the tooltips are turned off, and tooltips appear again for me when I click the box zoom magnify icon a second time to deactivate it.

Comment: OK so that explains it. Now how did you infer that behavior?

Comment: oh and pls go ahead and make an answer so I can award.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the pan-and-zoom tool (crossed arrows icon), tooltips should remain unchanged after zooming.  If you use the box zoom (magnifier icon), while box zoom is active, the tooltips are turned off.  The tooltips should appear again after clicking the box zoom magnify icon a second time to deactivate it.
[image]
Perhaps this UI could be clearer.

[Here is scatter plot with tooltips example you can use to see this in action](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html).